# Homotopy invariance of pullbacks of principal bundles

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, principal-bundles, classifying-spaces

This is the proof of [lemma 7.2](https://www3.nd.edu/~mbehren1/18.906/prin.pdf) in a notes by Stephen Mitchell, on classifying spaces.

Essentially one step of the proof claims that:

> Let $p:Y \rightarrow B \times I$ be a principal bundle. If $B$ is a CW complex, and $s:B \times \{0 \} \rightarrow Y$ is a section. Then there is an extension $s':B \times I \rightarrow Y$.

It says this follows from general property of Serre fibrations. (where the author also says should be in [this set of notes](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e737/a4f8b93242910c050c2faf761236dcf60f64.pdf). )

*How is this so?*

Comment: This is the homotopy lifting property, discussed on page 2 of the notes you link to. Take $X=B$, $Y=E$, $f=s$ and $G=pr_1$.

Comment: My confusion is why does $p$ has the HLP against $B \times 0 $ to $B \times I$. In fact, is it true that $p$ is a Serre fibration?

Comment: A locally trivial map over a CW complex is always a fibration. This is a theorem originally due to Dold. There is an extended discussion in Jeff Strom's Book *Modern Classical Homotopy Theory* in section 13.

Comment: It seems to me that this is true with out being over CW complex? I think its in section 6 of notes in Serre fibrations I linked.

Comment: It's true over a paracompact space (CW complexes are paracompact). I'm not sure if it holds in more generality.